# How to Filter Datatable or Dataview with common Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, datatable

I have a `DataTable` with transaction details, it contains details about invoices and payments relevant to those invoices and also other payments.

In my `DataTable` payments relevant to that invoices will have an invoice number. I want to filter out every other payment details and only want to show invoices and and payments relevant to that invoices that is I want to show only transactions with same invoice number. How to do it?

Comment: You want to Filter with Invoice Number on he data table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Lets consider that **dt** contains the Invoice details. I am converting that to a dataview and applying the Filter with Invoice Number to Filter the data.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt, string.Format("InvoiceNumber='{0}'", 1),"",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        dt = dv.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the Select Method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/way3dy9w(v=vs.110).aspx